# Complicated AST manipulation looks ugly in C++. How to refactor it?

Tags: c++

Here is [a code I have recently written in the compiler for my programming language](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly/blob/943ceeebc4dcce85a119029d128069e3c68114a2/compiler.cpp#L945), written in C++.  It rewrites code such as:

> ```
> array_name[random_generator()] += 1;
> ```

to a code such as:

> ```
> Integer32 temporary_subscriptXXXX;
> temporary_subscriptXXXX := random_generator();
> array_name[temporary_subscriptXXXX] :=
>   array_name[temporary_subscriptXXXX] + 1;
> ```

Notice that simply rewriting it as something like:

> ```
> array_name[random_generator()] := array_name[random_generator()]
>                   + 1;
> ```

would not do the trick, because then the random generator would
have been called twice instead of once, each time presumably
giving a different result.

---

````cpp
  } else if (text.size() == 2 and
             text[1] ==
                 '=') // The assignment operators "+=", "-=", "*=" and "/="...
  {
    if (children.at(0).text.back() ==
        '[') { // https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly/issues/15
               // https://discord.com/channels/530598289813536771/847014270922391563/934823770307301416
               /*
                * So, what follows is a bit of an ugly and incomprehensible code
                * that does the following. It rewrites code such as:
                * ```
                * array_name[random_generator()] += 1;
                * ```
                * to a code such as:
                * ```
                * Integer32 temporary_subscriptXXXX;
                * temporary_subscriptXXXX := random_generator();
                * array_name[temporary_subscriptXXXX] :=
                *   array_name[temporary_subscriptXXXX] + 1;
                * ```
                * Notice that simply rewriting it as something like:
                * ```
                * array_name[random_generator()] := array_name[random_generator()]
                *                   + 1;
                * ```
                * would not do the trick, because then the random generator would
                * have been called twice instead of once, each time presumably
                * giving a different result.
                * TODO: Refactor that code to be more legible. I have made a
                *   StackExchange question asking how to do that, but it got
                *   closed for some reason:
                *   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273535/complicated-ast-manipulation-looks-ugly-in-c-how-to-refactor-it
                */
      TreeNode fakeInnerFunctionNode("Does", lineNumber, columnNumber);
      std::string subscriptName =
          "temporary_subscript" + std::to_string(rand());
      while (context.variableTypes.count(subscriptName))
        subscriptName = "temporary_subscript" + std::to_string(rand());
      TreeNode declarationOfSubscript("Integer32", lineNumber, columnNumber);
      declarationOfSubscript.children.push_back(
          TreeNode(subscriptName, lineNumber, columnNumber));
      fakeInnerFunctionNode.children.push_back(declarationOfSubscript);
      TreeNode subscriptAssignment(":=", lineNumber, columnNumber);
      subscriptAssignment.children.push_back(
          TreeNode(subscriptName, lineNumber, columnNumber));
      subscriptAssignment.children.push_back(children[0].children.at(0));
      fakeInnerFunctionNode.children.push_back(subscriptAssignment);
      TreeNode convertedToSimpleAssignment(":=", lineNumber, columnNumber);
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children.push_back(TreeNode(
          children[0].text, children[0].lineNumber, children[0].columnNumber));
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[0].children.push_back(
          TreeNode(subscriptName, lineNumber, columnNumber));
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children.push_back(
          TreeNode(text.substr(0, 1), lineNumber, columnNumber));
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].children.push_back(TreeNode(
          children[0].text, children[0].lineNumber, children[0].columnNumber));
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].children[0].children.push_back(
          TreeNode(subscriptName, lineNumber, columnNumber));
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].children.push_back(
          children.at(1));
      fakeInnerFunctionNode.children.push_back(convertedToSimpleAssignment);
      CompilationContext fakeContext = context;
      fakeContext.stackSizeOfThisScope = 0;
      fakeContext.stackSizeOfThisFunction = 0;
      assembly += fakeInnerFunctionNode.compile(fakeContext) + "\n";
    } else {
      TreeNode convertedToSimpleAssignment(":=", lineNumber, columnNumber);
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children.push_back(children[0]);
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children.push_back(*this);
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].text =
          convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].text.substr(0, 1);
      assembly += convertedToSimpleAssignment.compile(context);
    }
````

It definitely looks incomprehensible. How would you write it better?

Comment: Please note that all code to be reviewed must be included in the question. At the moment I don't think we have enough context to say much. What are the first condition(s) of the `else if`? What are `children` and `text`? What does this code do? What's does `TreeNode` look like? What does `CompilationContext` look like?

Comment: So you are doing some AST manipulation. And you noticed that the code is hard to understand. But you seem to expect us to be able to understand how you are manipulating the AST from that hard to understand code on an AST where we don't even know the grammar? Please [edit] your question to give readers the chance to understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest improvement you can make is simply to *use reasonably short names.* [Name length should be proportional to scope length](https://moderatemisbehaviour.github.io/clean-code-smells-and-heuristics/names/n5-use-long-names-for-long-scopes.html); there is no reason to have names like `convertedToSimpleAssignment` as local variables.

Just by renaming, your `else` branch goes from

```
  TreeNode convertedToSimpleAssignment(":=", lineNumber, columnNumber);
  convertedToSimpleAssignment.children.push_back(children[0]);
  convertedToSimpleAssignment.children.push_back(*this);
  convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].text =
      convertedToSimpleAssignment.children[1].text.substr(0, 1);
  assembly += convertedToSimpleAssignment.compile(context);
```

down to simply

```
  auto n = TreeNode(":=", lineNumber, columnNumber);
  n.children.push_back(children[0]);
  n.children.push_back(*this);
  n.children[1].text = n.children[1].text.substr(0, 1);
  assembly += n.compile(context);
```

Also, `s.substr(0, 1)` is just `s[0]`, so:

```
  n.children[1].text = n.children[1].text[0];
```

Your next step would be to look at operations you do over and over, and factor them out into functions so that the code reflects a high-level view of what you're doing. For example, this specific bit seems to be creating a node with two children and a "text" in the middle (the name of the operator). So I'd look for a way to write it as:

```
  text = text[0];  // turn "+=" into "+", "*=" into "*", etc
  auto n = TreeNode(
      line, column,
      ":=", { children[0], *this }
  );
  assembly += n.compile(ctx);
```

Then, try to apply the same techniques throughout your code.

Comment: `.emplace_back()` might also help...